# Parsing XML with external tags in Python

Tags: python, xml

I am currently trying to print some XML tags value, btw tags are provided by an external text file. I'm using this loop :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish


tree=ET.parse('file.xml')
root=tree.getroot()

with open('taglist.txt', 'r') as taglist:
    for line in taglist:
        tag=line
        print(tag)
        for tag in root.findall("./"+tag):
            result=tag.text
            print(result)
```

My XML file is a report generated by PingCastle and looks like :

```
<root>
      <tag1>Value1</tag1>
            <tag1.1>Value</tag1.1>
      <tag2>Value2</tag2>
      <tag3>Value3</tag3>
</root>
```

But my output only retrieves me the last value like :

```
DomainFQDN

GlobalScore

StaleObjectsScore

PrivilegiedGroupScore

TrustScore

AnomalyScore
100
```

My input text file containing the tags looks like:

```
tag1
tag2
tag3
```

I'm quite new in the dev world if you please mind help me, would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: FWIW since you wrote that you're new to development, it's very important to develop a sense of *data abstraction*.  For example, ask yourself, is your problem really related to the fact that you're reading a list of XML tag names from a file?  I think it probably isn't really relevant.  Try instead just making a Python list like `tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']` containing some examples from your real file, and experiment with that.  Or for that matter, try to make sure it works for extracting just *one* tag of interest.

Comment: In any case, without showing some of the XML file or explaining exactly what you want to parse from it it's hard to help.  We can't know without more context what you mean by "only retrieves the last value" or why that's a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just tried to parse with a list containing some of the tags I need and it actually works. I also added a bit of XML using the same tree as my XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to strip the "\n" ending each line of my file... :')

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your input text looks like, but you are making some mistakes naming your variables.

tag=line is setting the tag variable equal to the line of text

tag in root.findall.... is resetting the tag variable to iterate through the elements found in the findall.

I believe you could get rid of the first for loop because a findall will return a list that you can iterate through instead of iterating through the page, then also iterating through the list generated from the page.

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish


tree=ET.parse('file.xml')
root=tree.getroot()

with open('taglist.txt', 'r') as taglist:
   taglist = input_text.findall("./tag")
   for tag in taglist:
      result = tag.text
```

Something like this may work better. I can't really test it without having a better idea of what your input looks like though.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I updated the thread as the commrent section didnt allow me to put a string on each line...